# Making a dropdown tab using Angular2.0 and Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Following the tutorials and examples from [angular.io](http://angular.io) and the static navbar from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/#), I have this snippet in the template for `app.component`

```
<li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">My Company <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a [routerLink]="['MyProfilePage']">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['MyCataloguePage']">Catalogue</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['MyQuotationPage']">Products on Sale</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['MyContractsPage']">Contracts</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

However, nothing happens when you click the dropdown button. The original `<a class="dropdown-toggle">` had an href, which didn't work because I didn't have a path for it. I tried making another component with those inner `<li>` just so I could add a `[routerLink]` to the dropdown-toggle, but it gave me an error about how children paths were not allowed.

Any ideas on how I can achieve the dropdown working like in the bootstrap link above? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution is that you need to use the right derective like that:

import {DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bs-dropdown/dropdown';

and don't forget to use this in component like :

directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES]

That's all. I hope this works for you.